# event listener, one css transform ends and another is started

Tags: javascript, webkit, transform, event-listener

I have a css transform that happens when a button is clicked shown here http://jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/5/

I'm not sure if this possible but, would it be possible to make a event listener or perhaps there's a different method, so when that button is clicked and the transform is complete another class replaces that transform class that just finished and makes a second animation.  I want to avoid using keyframe animation because I'm having an issue with that particular method where I want to use the end state of the animation for a transform, but it resets.  You can see that issue here http://jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/23/

Basically I'd like the animation to run it's course (it's two step), finish, and then be able to click another button to have other transforms happen.  Like here http://jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/21/ except the starting transform is only one step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `transitionend` event fires whenever a CSS transition finishes.  You can listen for that event from your first transition and then start the second transition when that event fires.

Keep in mind that there are vendor-specific prefixes on the `transitionend` event name in some browsers.

What you could do in this case is the follow sequence:

1. Button is clicked
2. Add event listender for transitionend event on the target object
3. Make change that starts the first transition
4. When transitionend event fires, remove event listener to you don't get confused with other transitions ending
5. Make change that starts the second transition

You can see a working version of multi-stage transitions here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5FnwY/

Comment: hmm, okay, I'm new the javascript, very new, so I just did some research and if I did space_collapse.AddEventListener(transitionend, name of function that replaces one class with another?) would that work?  I'm having trouble implementing that into my page, and I'm not sure where I went wrong (possibly completely wrong?)

Comment: Nice. Also, see an example for "Detecting the completion of a Transition" on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions

Comment: Because of the incomplete standards for CSS3 transitions, the transition event name is different in different browsers.  The event names used are "transitionend" (Mozilla), "webkitTransitionEnd" (Safari, Chrome), "oTransitionEnd" (Opera).

Comment: @loriensleafs - here's a version that works in Chrome: jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5FnwY. You can see the javascript I used and I had to change the structure of the way transitions were defined a bit to get it to go from one transition to the next.

Comment: that's great, I have some questions about it, but I have to go through it a bit more before I ask them, but thanks a ton.

Comment: okay first question, I want for the final of this I'd like each layer to ultimately be able to do this with one button click, so do I have to make a seperate "start" function for all of the layers?  For example I updated what you had done to try to get two layers to do this but some how it's not working, can you look at it? http://jsfiddle.net/mbKu6/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mbKu6/6/ this one I tried using two separate functions for the different layers, this didn't work either

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mbKu6/10/  so I have this working how I want it to except that I added another button called back and I'm trying to have it play the two step animation backwards but I can't seem to get it to work, any thoughts on that?

Comment: this is the closest I can get and it doesn't work  http://jsfiddle.net/mbKu6/11/  it won't let me post the function, but it's stars_goback